# Java complains about final field not initialized in default case of a switch

Tags: java

I want to initialize a final field in different ways. Therefore I have created an enumeration type and perform a switch over it.

```
    public enum TYPE {
        A,
        B,
    }
```

I have also added a default case to the switch with an assertion to warn my fellow programmers in case they add a new enumeration constant and
forget to update the switch.

```
        default:
            assert false : "missing TYPE detected";
```

Java however detects the flaw in my argument and complains that the blank field may not have been initialized. How should I deal with this situation?

```
public class SwitchExample
{
    public enum TYPE {
        A,
        B,
    }

    private final int foo;

    public SwitchExample(TYPE t)
    {
        switch (t) {
        case A:
            foo = 11;
            break;

        case B:
            foo = 22;
            break;

        default:
            assert false : "missing TYPE detected";
        }

        // The blank final field foo may not have been initialized
    }
}
```

Comment: then just initialize it in your `default`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the `assert false : "missing TYPE detected";` you may throw an `IllegalArgumentException("missing TYPE detected")`

Answer (score 0):

As you re-assign foo reference

```
foo = 11;
```

you cannot declare it as final

```
private final int foo;
```

See http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html

Comment: You can assign value of a `final` variable inside constructor

Comment: You don't have to initialise a final variable at the point of declaration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_variables

Comment: Ok :) I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

You can change code after your `default` to something like this:

```
assert (foo = 0) > 0 : "missing TYPE detected";
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the `final` keyword you are forced to set its value in all cases in your switch statement. To get around this, just set your `foo` to a value you know means that an error has occured e.g. `-1`